# Probability of traffic sign matching

Tags: probability

Suppose I arrived at one small local area(round 10meters), and I brought one map, which says there are 2 traffic signs(A, B) in this local area. But actually I only found one traffic sign, so there is 3 perhaps:

1. this sign is A
2. is B
3. it is one new sign which isn't on the map

my problem is， what matric can be used to describe the possibility of the 3 decisions. Thanks for any ideas

[image: sign postion]

Answer (score 0):

Given that your situation seems to have little information, I guess the most reasonnable assumption is that :

$$P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1-P(C)}{2}$$
since you don't seem to indicate any particular reason why the traffic light would be A rather than B. And hopefully $P(C)$ is small because it is more or less the probability that your map is correct.

Then if we have information about position it is very different. The probability of finding a given sign (A or B) is the probability of being in its surrounding, and the probability of C is the probability that you are indeed not close to any of the other two signs.

Do you have any more details you can give on the probability distribution of your position, and what you mean by "finding a sign"? Do you just know it is here or have you covered a given area?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. If there is no other information,  we can give A and B one big probability, and C little probability. But if we can know the position of the signs, so what can we improve the result.

Comment: em, for the 3 signs, the position probability distribution(PDF)  is 2D Gaussian distribution in the earth local plane.